# ArrayList problem while deleating

Tags: java, android, collections

hi i have a problem with Arraylist objects here is my code

```
ArrayList<String> globlalArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); //declared in some other class
ArrayList<String> TempArray = getsomeTempObjects()//method
globlalArrayList = TempArray;
TempArray.clear();  //Here the Problem
```

**in above code i want to clear all TempArray obj. but it is also clearing globlalArrayList**
Can Any one tell me what happening and how can i achieve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use just reference copy. Use [`addAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
globlalArrayList.addAll(TempArray);
```

What you do now is just referencing one object from two references. If you make manipulation one, it is all refletected on the second, as they reference to 1(one) object.

P.S. Java uses camelCase style, so please name your array as `tempArray`.

Comment: yeah i tried this one Also,but it is also clearing globlalArrayList

Comment: i am sorry i did a mistake earlier. so now working     addAll() method